# Android Coroutine JUnit test failed

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, junit4

I'm new in kotlin testing. Today I will try first UnitTest

I have this testing class:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asSharedFlow

open class ChangesNotifier<T> {

    private val triggerFlow = MutableSharedFlow<T>()

    var updates = triggerFlow.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun notify(data: T) {
        triggerFlow.emit(data)
    }
}
```

And write this test using JUnit4:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.advanceUntilIdle
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class ChangesNotifierTest {

    private lateinit var notifier: ChangesNotifier<Int>
    private var result = 0

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        notifier = ChangesNotifier()
    }

       @Test
    fun `Check what notifier receiving updates`() = runTest {
        launch {
            notifier.updates.collectLatest {
                result = it
            }
        }

        launch {
            notifier.notify(100)
        }

        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(100, result)
    }
}
```

But test fails with this exception:

```
expected:<100> but was:<0>
Expected :100
Actual   :0
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<100> but was:<0>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
```

Looks like updates does not emmitted...

Sample from official google documentation:
https://github.com/android/snippets/blob/7322f58994e9ade5ffee8e49f956e4a97339f384/kotlin/src/test/kotlin/com/example/android/coroutines/testing/StandardTestDispatcherTest.kt#L43-L52

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Test
fun `Check what notifier receiving updates`(): Unit = runTest {
    val values = mutableListOf<Int>()
    backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)){
        notifier.updates.toList(values)
    }
    notifier.notify(100);
    assertEquals(100, values[0])
}
```

After testing things out and researching on android dev the correct way of testing flows should be this.

Because the flow exposed by the ChangeNotifier here never completes, the toList call that's collecting it never returns. Starting the collecting coroutine in TestScope.backgroundScope ensures that the coroutine gets cancelled before the end of the test. Otherwise, runTest would keep waiting for its completion, causing the test to stop responding and eventually fail.

Notice how UnconfinedTestDispatcher is used for the collecting coroutine here. This ensures that the collecting coroutine is launched eagerly and is ready to receive values after launch returns.